# Permutations of nested parentheses (Dyck words)

Tags: function-construction, combinatorics, permutation

How would I construct a function that outputs [Dyck Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language)?

e.g. - there are 14 words in $\mathcal{D}_{8}$:

```
`[[[[]]]], [[[][]]], [[[]][]], [[][[]]], [[[]]][], [[][][]], [][[[]]], 
 [[][]][], [[]][[]], [][[][]], [[]][][], [][[]][], [][][[]], [][][][]`
```

There is an equivalent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404031/number-of-ways-of-correctly-arranging-parenthesis), but the answer only gives information about the number of cases.

I was playing around with things like

```
nest[n_] := 
DeleteCases[Quiet[ToExpression /@ (StringReplace[#, "}{" -> "},{"] & /@ 
StringJoin /@ Permutations[Flatten@Array[{"{", "}"} &, n], {2 n}])], $Failed]
```

... will keep at it!

Comment: I have a simple python version over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559971/algorithm-to-print-all-valid-combations-of-n-pairs-of-parenthesis/41562110#41562110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another compiled implementation for generating Dyck words in lexicographic order, this time using [Knuth's "Algorithm P"](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=IkuEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT656):

```
dyckBits = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
                   Module[{c, db, f, j, k, m, s, t, v, w, bitEncInts},
                          m = n - 1; c = t = 2^m; s = Quotient[8 c - 1, 3];
                          db = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]];
                          While[True, Internal`StuffBag[db, s];
                                s = BitOr[s, c]; f = Quotient[c, 2];
                                If[BitAnd[Quotient[s, f], 1] == 1,
                                   m--; c = f;
                                   s = BitAnd[s, BitNot[c]],
                                   j = m - 1; k = n - 1; v = f; w = t;
                                   While[BitAnd[Quotient[s, v], 1] == 0,
                                         s = BitOr[BitAnd[s, BitNot[w]], v];
                                         j--; k -= 2;
                                         v = Quotient[v, 2]; w = Quotient[w, 4]];
                                   If[j == 0, Break[]];
                                   s = BitAnd[s, BitNot[v]];
                                   m = n - 1; c = t]];
                          bitEncInts = Quotient[Internal`BagPart[db, All], 2];
                          IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] & /@ bitEncInts],
                   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(* thanks to Jacob Akkerboom *)
ccConv = Compile[{{dyckBits, _Integer, 2}}, Subtract[93, 2 dyckBits],
                 RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

dyckWordsCc[n_Integer?EvenQ] := FromCharacterCode[ccConv[dyckBits[n]]]
```

The choice to use bits to represent the Dyck words lends itself well to using compilation, so I've found this to be much faster than the routine in my other post.

```
dyckWordsCc[8]
   {"[][][][]", "[[]][][]", "[][[]][]", "[[][]][]", "[[[]]][]", "[][][[]]", "[[]][[]]",
    "[][[][]]", "[[][][]]", "[[[]][]]", "[][[[]]]", "[[][[]]]", "[[[][]]]", "[[[[]]]]"}
```

---

For reference, here's the version of "Algorithm P" that directly works with strings:

```
dyckStrings[n_Integer?EvenQ] := Module[{j, k, m, s},
            m = n; s = StringJoin[Prepend[ConstantArray["[]", n/2], "]"]];
            Reap[While[True, Sow[StringDrop[s, 1]];
                       s = StringReplacePart[s, "]", {m, m}];
                       If[StringPart[s, m - 1] === "]",
                          m--; s = StringReplacePart[s, "[", {m, m}],
                          j = m - 1; k = n;
                          While[StringPart[s, j] === "[",
                                s = StringReplacePart[s, {"[", "]"}, {{k, k}, {j, j}}];
                                j--; k -= 2];
                          If[j == 1, Break[]];
                          s = StringReplacePart[s, "[", {j, j}]; m = n]]
                 ][[-1, 1]]]
```

It is quite a bit slower.

Comment: Hey J.M., I made a mn adaptation of your answer. It appears there was a different way to do the post processing that was more efficient.

Comment: I felt it was best to merge my adaptation into your answer. I renamed the function `dyckWordsCc`, where `Cc` stands for `CharacterCode`. I think all this makes it easier to compare timings. I also think this makes it easier for somebody who just wants to copy paste some nice code to find the right definition.

Comment: @Jacob, I'm OK with it.

Comment: This is fast!  But it also uses an order of magnitude more memory than my recursion does.  Can that be improved?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, can you try [the routine in the first version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/141224/1) to see if it also consumes a lot of memory?

Comment: @J.M. It seems that your original version used less memory (twice as much as Mr. W's. Mr.W's is essentially the output `ByteCount`). In particular the original `dyckBits` is quite efficient. It seems most memory is used in the `ccConv` step. Compiling `ccConv` was contraproductive, things are both faster and more memory efficient if we do not do this. I'm pretty sure a LibraryLink solution for `ccConv` would use considerably less memory.

Answer (score 17):

#### `StringReplaceList`

I just realized that there is a comparatively clean though not highly efficient way to write this using [`StringReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplaceList.html):

```
op = Union @@ StringReplaceList[#, {"[]" -> "[[]]", "[]" -> "[][]"}] &;

Nest[op, {"[]"}, 3] // Column
```

> ```
> [[[[]]]]
> [[[][]]]
> [[[]][]]
> [[[]]][]
> [[][[]]]
> [[][][]]
> [[][]][]
> [[]][[]]
> [[]][][]
> [][[[]]]
> [][[][]]
> [][[]][]
> [][][[]]
> [][][][]
> ```

#### Better recursion

Replacing my earlier recursive method, this time avoiding redundancy.  I keep track of the number of *open* and *close* brackets as each builds toward *n*.

```
f[n_] := f[n, 1, 0, "["]

f[n_, n_, c_, r_] := {r <> ConstantArray["]", n - c]}

f[n_, o_, c_, r_] /; c < o := 
  f[n, o + 1, c, r <> "["] ~Join~ f[n, o, c + 1, r <> "]"]

f[n_, o_, c_, r_] := f[n, o + 1, c, r <> "["] 

f[4]
```

> ```
> {"[[[[]]]]", "[[[][]]]", "[[[]][]]", "[[[]]][]",
>  "[[][[]]]", "[[][][]]", "[[][]][]", "[[]][[]]",
>  "[[]][][]", "[][[[]]]", "[][[][]]", "[][[]][]",
>  "[][][[]]", "[][][][]"}
> ```

Reasonably usable:

```
(* D24 *)

f[12] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {1.15, 208012}
> ```

### Benchmarking

Here is a benchmark of various methods posted.  All functions modified to use *n* rather than *n/2*.

*Now using gwr's simplified code*

```
(* Coolwater's method as a function *)
cw[n_] := 
 StringJoin @@@ (Pick[#, Min@*Accumulate /@ #, 0] &[
     Permutations[Join[#, -#] &[ConstantArray[1, n]]]] /. {-1 -> "]", 1 -> "["})

op = Union @@ StringReplaceList[#, {"[]" -> "[[]]", "[]" -> "[][]"}] &;
f2[n_] := Nest[op, {"[]"}, n - 1]

(* f code as above *)

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{DyckWord, f, f2, cw, dyckWords}, # &, Range @ 12, 
  "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: looks great - will have a play aroud with it - thanks!

Comment: @martin I knew filtering was a sign of a bad algorithm.  Please see my new code that avoids this.

Comment: Re the latest, I was just about to post the same thing with rule `x_ -> "[]" ~~ x`

Comment: @Simon Very concise!  But it comes at the cost of more redundancy that has to be filtered out with `Union`.  Can you think of a pattern that gives *less* redundancy?

Comment: I cannot. I think there might be a neat method using Groupings, but it's bedtime here.

Comment: Very elegant solutions (+1). The `StringListReplace` approach is a cool one.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like this:

### Test for Dyck words

We could test for Dyck words by consistently replacing "[ ]" with the empty word $\epsilon$. If the sequence of parentheses is a Dyck word, then in the end we must obtain the empty word. Thus:

```
DyckWordQ[ s_String ] := With[
    {
        f = StringReplace[
              {
                  "[" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "]" -> "", 
                  "[]"                     -> ""
              }
        ]
    },
    If[
        FixedPoint[ f, s ] === "",
        (* then *)        True,
        (* else *)        False,
        (* unevaluated *) False
    ]
]
```

### Constructor for Dyck words

We could then use this to select valid Dyck words from all possible permutations.

```
DyckWord[ n_Integer ] /; EvenQ[n] := With[
    {
        p = Permutations[ ConstantArray[ "[", n/2 ] ~ Join ~ ConstantArray[ "]", n/2] ]
    },
    p // RightComposition[
        Map[ StringJoin ],
        Select[#, DyckWordQ] &
    ]
]

DyckWord[8]
```

> {"[[[[]]]]", "[[[][]]]", "[[[]][]]", "[[[]]][]", "[[][[]]]", \
>   "[[][][]]", "[[][]][]", "[[]][[]]", "[[]][][]", "[][[[]]]", \
>   "[][[][]]", "[][[]][]", "[][][[]]", "[][][][]"}

Comment: I wanted to benchmark this code but it does not copy and paste properly.  Would you please check it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There is a missing ] after n/2. This runs for me.  With[{p = 
   Permutations[ConstantArray[0, n/2]~Join~ConstantArray[1, n/2]]}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the edit; it was kind of late when I pasted this. While it is not the fastest method, I would argue, that it is quite readable, a feature I often find rather important looking at what differences in timing we are talking about here... :)

Comment: @gwr also development time. If it takes 1 hour to come up with something that runs in .02 seconds and 5 minutes development time for something that runs in 5 seconds... "
Remember also the human overhead of writing this if it is not going to be used many times.- Mr.Wizard" But since this might be used many times and for larger ones...

Comment: @bobbym Sure, but try `f[16]` or `cw[16]` (D32) and see how fast that is... `f[18]` will probably take around 50 minutes already.

Comment: @gwr that is what I meant by my last sentence. Speed over simplicity is called for here and usually in other places too.

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
d = 16
If[EvenQ[d], StringJoin @@@ (Pick[#, Min@*Accumulate /@ #, 0] &[
 Permutations[Join[#, -#] &[ConstantArray[1, d/2]]]] /. {-1 -> "]", 1 -> "["})]
```

Comment: As filtering approaches go this is a nice one!

Comment: Teeny simplification over Coolwater's nice answer:  `f[d_?EvenQ] := 
 StringJoin @@@ (Pick[#, Min@*Accumulate /@ #, 0] &[
     Permutations[Join[#, -#] &[ConstantArray[1, d/2]]]] /. {-1 -> 
      "]", 1 -> "["})`

Answer (score 4):

Not fast, but quite pleasing IMO, using [`Groupings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html)

```
f[x_, y_] := f[x] <> "[" <> f[y] <> "]"
f[s_String] := s
f[_Integer] := ""

dyck[n_] := Groupings[n + 1, f -> 2]

dyck[4]

(* {"[][][][]", "[[][][]]", "[[][]][]", "[[[][]]]", 
"[[]][][]", "[[[]][]]", "[[[]]][]", "[[[[]]]]", "[][[]][]", 
"[[][[]]]", "[][][[]]", "[][[][]]", "[[]][[]]", "[][[[]]]"} *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test or benchmark this in v10.1

Answer (score 4):

I made a function using LibraryLink. It uses the same algorithm as the one in J.M.'s answer, i.e. algorithm P by Knuth. Here is the C code

```c
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static char* charbuf;
static mint curword;
static mint zz;

/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}

DLLEXPORT int set_permup_buf(WolframLibraryData libData,
                             mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

    //    '[' = 0      and    ']' = 1

    curword = 0;
    zz = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);

    mint qq = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
    //sizeof(char) == 1 is guaranteed by the C standard. 
    charbuf = malloc(qq * (zz + 1));

    mint mm = zz - 1;
    mint jj;

    char aAr[zz + 1];
    int rowNum = 0;

    char b = 1;
    char* aPtr = aAr;

    //    p1
    for(int kk = 0; kk <= zz; kk++){
        *aPtr = b;
        aPtr++;
        b = !b;
    }

p2: {
    for(int dd = 0; dd < zz; dd++){
        charbuf[(zz + 1)*rowNum + dd] = 91 + 2 * aAr[dd+1];
    }
    charbuf[(zz+1)*rowNum + zz] = '\0';
    rowNum++;
}

    //p3
    aAr[mm] = 1;
    if(aAr[mm-1]){
        aAr[mm-1] = 0;
        mm--; goto p2;
    }

    //p4
    jj = mm - 1;
    int kk = zz - 1;
    while(! aAr[jj]){
        aAr[jj] = 1;
        aAr[kk] = 0;
        jj--;
        kk-=2;
    }

    //p5
    if(jj){
        aAr[jj] = 0;
        mm = zz - 1;
        goto p2;
    }

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

DLLEXPORT int get_permup_str(WolframLibraryData libData,
                             mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    MArgument_setUTF8String(Res, charbuf + curword*(zz+1));
    curword++;
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

DLLEXPORT int cleanup(WolframLibraryData libData,
                             mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    free(charbuf); //seems magical, doesn't it?
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

**Loading the function**

Save the code above at file at the path `yourFileName` (maybe the name of the file should end in `.c`) .

```
<< CCompilerDriver`
libName = "dyckwordlib";
lib2 = CreateLibrary[File@yourFileName, libName, "Debug" -> True];
setBuf = LibraryFunctionLoad[libName, 
   "set_permup_buf", {_Integer, _Integer}, "Void"];
getStr = LibraryFunctionLoad[libName, "get_permup_str", {}, 
   "UTF8String"];
cleanup = LibraryFunctionLoad[libName, "cleanup", {}, "Void"];
dyckWordsLibl[kwnn_] :=
 Module[{kn, qq, res}
  ,
  qq = CatalanNumber[kwnn];
  setBuf[2 kwnn, qq];
  res = Table[
    getStr[]
    ,
    qq
    ];
  cleanup[];
  res
  ]
```

**Timings and naive memory tracking**.

We see that the LibraryLink solution is fast. It also does not consume much memory, although I am pretty sure the memory monitoring tools of Mathematica don't accurately track the memory used.

```
MaxMemoryUsed[dyckWordsLibl[12]]
resJac = dyckWordsLibl[12]; // RepeatedTiming // First
MaxMemoryUsed[dyckWordsCc[24]]
resCc = dyckWordsCc[24]; // RepeatedTiming // First
MaxMemoryUsed[f[12]]
resWiz = f[12]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 14978472
> 0.10
> 159753824
> 0.34
> 16641256
> 1.397
> ```

Of course the results are the same

```
Sort[resJac]  === Sort[resCc] === Sort[resWiz]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Using (slight adaptations of) definitions from especially Mr.Wizards answer, we get the following `BenchmarkPlot`

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{wizf, f2, cw, dyckWordsCcDouble, dyckWordsLibl}, # &, 
 Range[2, 15], "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 10]
```

[image]

**Considerations about `MaxMemoryUsed`**

Considering that on most platforms a char is encoded in one byte (and on mine in particular), the real memory used by our function is the following (a bit more than Mr.Wizard's function)

```
With[{kwnn = 12,
  qq = CatalanNumber[kwnn]},
 ByteCount@resJac + qq * (2 kwnn + 1) ]
```

> ```
> 20177244
> ```

Below, we will show below that `MaxMemoryUsed` does not track all the memory used by comparing the value `MaxMemoryUsed[setBuf[2 kwnn, qq]]`, which is very small, with an alternative measurement.

We can track the increase in memory using a performance monitoring tool, in my case on OSX I used Activity Monitor. The increase in memory used by the WolframKernel process closely corresponds to the amount of memory we asked for using malloc. We set `before` and `after` to correspond to the values we see in activity monitor. We increase `kwnn` to `16` to make the memory use stand out even more.

```
before = Quantity[52.2, "Megabytes"];    
kwnn = 16;
qq = CatalanNumber[kwnn];
MaxMemoryUsed[setBuf[2 kwnn, qq]]
```

> ```
> 112
> ```

Of course this number `112` does not really make sense. We look again in activity monitor

```
after = Quantity[1.14, "Gigabytes"];
```

Incidentally, using the tool we can now see that cleanup works

```
cleanup[]; (*look in the tool after this command*)
```

Now we compare

```
Module[{kwnn = 16,
  qq },
 qq = CatalanNumber[kwnn];
  N@UnitConvert[qq * (2 kwnn + 1) Quantity[1, "Bytes"] , 
   Quantity[1, "Megabytes"]]]
  after - before
```

> ```
> 1166.8 MB
> 1087.8 MB
> ```

We see that we memory we used roughly corresponds to the memory we asked for. Furthermore, using the tool (activity monitor) we can see that `cleanup` works and all our memory is returned to us, so thats nice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a compiled implementation of an algorithm due to [Kása](http://www.acta.sapientia.ro/acta-info/C1-1/info1-9.pdf):

```
dyckPos = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
                  Module[{m = Quotient[n, 2], b, chk, db},
                         b = Range[2, n, 2]; db = Internal`Bag[Most[{1}]];
                         While[Internal`StuffBag[db, b, 1];
                               chk = False;
                               Do[If[b[[j]] < m + j, b[[j]]++;
                                     Do[b[[i]] = Max[b[[i - 1]] + 1, 2 i],
                                        {i, j + 1, m - 1}];
                                     chk = True; Break[]],
                                  {j, m - 1, 1, -1}];
                               chk];
                         Partition[Internal`BagPart[db, All], m]],
                  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

dyckWords[n_Integer?EvenQ] := 
    Table[StringJoin[ReplacePart[Range[n], {(Alternatives @@ pos) -> "]", _ -> "["}]],
          {pos, dyckPos[n]}]
```

Using the OP's example:

```
dyckWords[8]
   {"[][][][]", "[][][[]]", "[][[]][]", "[][[][]]", "[][[[]]]", "[[]][][]", "[[]][[]]",
    "[[][]][]", "[[][][]]", "[[][[]]]", "[[[]]][]", "[[[]][]]", "[[[][]]]", "[[[[]]]]"}
```